# How to close port 80 in windows vista?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, windows-vista, port

i have a virtual machine with OS server 2003 
connection bridged

i need to test if the webapplication on guest webserver will be available for users on the network, so i need to close port 80 on vista while still open on win server 2003, however, i can't close port 80 on vista

Comment: Which virtualization software are you using?

Comment: @Massimo: i am using vm player

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a bridged connections, then the virtual machine will have its own IP address on the same network the host system is connected to. So, opening and closing ports *on the host system* should have no relationship at all to which ports are available to the guest system.

This could change if you are using some form of NAT for your virtual machine networks; but definitely not if you are using a bridged connection.

About your question: port 80 is usually used by IIS on Windows system, so you should check if it's installed and running; if this is the case, you can either stop IIS (by stopping the "World Wide Web Publishing Service") or uninstall it from "Programs and Features", provided you don't actually need it, of course.

If IIS is not installed and/or not started, then something else is using port 80; you can use the command `netstat -nao` to check the PID of the owner process, and then use the Task Manager (by adding the PID column to the process list) to check which process is associated with that PID.

Comment: a friend of mine is not convinced with your opinion, can you provide an evidence

Comment: imean evidence that assures that VM ware can use the hardware regardless the setting of host OS

Comment: @mokokamello that is what network bridging means in a VMware environment, the Virtual Nics bypasses most of the host's network stack, and blocking ports at a higher layer in the host (such as closing TCP port 80 on the hosts ip-addresses) has no effect on what VMware's bridging is doing at the network layer, or in the guest. On more recent operating systems, and with certain software firewalls that act at a lower level this might not be true, as explained in this vmware KB article http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1004813

Comment: @Helvick: is there a way to bypass software / firewalls acting on lower levels.

Comment: @mokokamello - It depends on the implementation, that VMware link explains how to bypass the low level firewall on Vista\7\2008 if it is interfering with VMware Workstation\Player functionality, for other OS's or software firewalls that operate at lower levels there may be (probably will be) methods but they will be specific to each situation.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry, but VMWare company confess that the situation is different with windows vista

Troubleshooting blocked inbound network traffic on Windows Vista or 2008 after installing a VMware product
Symptoms

```
* Inbound network traffic stops after installing a VMware product.
* Networking fails.
*
  Blocked TCP/IP ports.
*
  Problems with networking on a Windows Vista or 2008 host.
```

Purpose
This article describes how to re-establish inbound network traffic to a computer with a Microsoft Vista or 2008 operating system that used to receive this traffic but suddenly stopped after a VMware product was installed.
Resolution
In some cases, the installation of a VMware product to a computer with a Microsoft Vista or 2008 operating system prevents all inbound networking traffic from reaching the computer. This is caused by the Windows Firewall assigning the VMware virtual NICs to the Public network.

Inbound networking traffic can be re-enabled by performing one of four corrective procedures.  Which procedure is performed depends on your environment and business requirements.  Each corrective procedure below has a summary of reasons for and against its use.
Reconfigure the Windows Firewall
This procedure requires extensive knowledge of the Windows Vista or 2008 operating system and its implementation of the Windows Firewall. Doing this ensures a permanent solution resulting in no unexpected behaviour in either the Windows operating system or the VMware product in use. Any description of the tasks required are beyond the scope of this article. For more information, refer to Windows operating system documentation.

Note: Only perform this if you have an in depth understanding of Windows Firewall.

Note: Modifying the access rules for the Public network will affect all NICs that belong to the Public network.

Move the VMware virtual NICs to the Private network
This procedure is simple to perform and has the least impact on both the Windows Vista or 2008 operating system and the VMware product in use. However, after any reboot of the operating system the NICs are moved back to the Public network again. Using this procedure requires supervision of the operating system to ensure that it is performed after every reboot.

To move the VMware virtual NICs to a Private network:

1. Click Start > Control Panel > Network and Sharing Center.
2. Click Customize.
3. Click Private.
4. Click Next.
   5.
     Click Close.

Disable the VMware virtual NICs
This procedure is simple to perform, but it prevents both NAT and Host Only networking from functioning in any virtual machine. Only Bridged networking is available. If neither NAT nor Host only networking is required, this is the simplest and most permanent procedure.

To disable the VMware virtual NICs:

1. Click Start > Control Panel > Network and Sharing Center.
   2.
     Click Manage network connections.
   3.
     Click VMware Network Adapter / VMnet1 / Unidentified network.
   4.
     Click Disable this network device.
   5.
     Click VMware Network Adapter / VMnet8 / Unidentified network.
   6.
     Click Disable this network device.

Redefine the VMware virtual NICs as endpoint devices
This procedure is permanent and allows for the continued use of Bridged, NAT, and Host Only networking. However, doing this causes the VMware virtual NICs to disappear from the Network and Sharing Center, even though they remain visible under Network Connections. This also causes the VMware virtual NICs to be exempt from all Windows Firewall access rules. When implemented, the control of virtual machine network access must be done from the guest operating system of each virtual machine. This bypasses the default security model of Windows Vista with respect to the the VMware virtual NICs, and the implications of using this procedure must be carefully considered.

To redefine the VMware virtual NICs as endpoint devices:

1. Click Start > Run.
   2.
     Type regedit and click OK.
   3.
     Double-click HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE>System>CurrentControlSet>Control>Class>{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}.

   Caution: VMware recommends that you back up this registry key before proceeding:

   ```
    1.
       If {4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318} is not still highlighted, click it.
    2.
       Click File > Export.
    3.
       Pick a location and name for the Registration File (*.reg) .
    4.
       Click Save.
   ```

   4.
     Click 0000.
   5.
     Look at the content of the Data field associated with the DriverDesc entry.
   6.
     If you see VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnetx , where x is replaced by a number, then:

   ```
    1.
       Right-click an empty space in the right content pane.
    2.
       Click New > Dword.
    3.
       Type *NdisDeviceType and press Enter.

       Note: Ensure to include the asterisk (* ) at the beginning of the entry.

    4.
       Double-click *NdisDeviceType.
    5.
       Type 1 and press Enter.
   ```

   7.
     Repeat steps 4-6, replacing 0000 in step 4 with the next entry in numerical order, until you have reached the end of all numerical entries.
   8.
     Follow the Disable the VMware virtual NICs section of this article above.
   9.
     Repeat step 8 but click Enable this network device instead.

http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1004813

Answer (score 1):

I think thhis may also imply on your case,
But I am sure now that VMWare on windows 7 connects far away from the Kernel of the Windows, that add space for firewalls to act